# How to use curve_fit in this scenario?

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting

Okay so i have two arrays T, and I0 of data.

I'm trying to fit this data onto an equation to find bandgap Eg. This is the code I have:

```
T = np.array([ 93, 100, 110, 130, 140, 159, 179, 195, 210, 224, 241, 255, 265,283, 293])
I0 = np.array([3.89071815e-05, 3.86379100e-05, 3.19573788e-05, 2.75543444e-05,3.00226067e-05, 3.59134864e-05, 3.92161213e-05, 4.37321918e-05,4.59245870e-05, 4.95912369e-05, 5.24583115e-05, 5.47069424e-05,5.73620696e-05, 5.80254459e-05, 7.23664434e-05])

def fit_func(T, Eg):
   T3 = T**3
   arg = -Eg/(kB * T)
   I0 = c*T3*np.exp(arg)
return I0 
params, cov = curve_fit(fit_func, T, I0, p0= 4.239e-19)
```

But this doesn't seem to work. The params gives me the exact same value as the initial guess, and cov is inf. I don't know what is wromg. please help.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is correct (but I would check it) then that function would appear to be best fitted with a *negative* value of `Eg`. (Or, alternatively, the sign of `Eg` is wrong in `arg` - could you link a reference for us to look at?)

The code below includes `c` as well as `Eg` as a parameter to be found. I'm assuming that `kB` is Boltzmann's constant.

The best fit appears to be

```
Eg, c =  -5.4109181863198085e-21 7.211320673443582e-13
```

but I'm really not convinced about your data.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np

kB = 1.380649e-23

T = np.array([ 93, 100, 110, 130, 140, 159, 179, 195, 210, 224, 241, 255, 265,283, 293])
I0 = np.array([3.89071815e-05, 3.86379100e-05, 3.19573788e-05, 2.75543444e-05,3.00226067e-05, 3.59134864e-05, 3.92161213e-05, 4.37321918e-05,4.59245870e-05, 4.95912369e-05, 5.24583115e-05, 5.47069424e-05,5.73620696e-05, 5.80254459e-05, 7.23664434e-05])

def fit_func( T, Eg, c ):                                                                                            
   return c * T ** 3 * np.exp( -Eg / ( kB * T ) )

Eg = -1.0e-20         # initial guess
c = 1.0e-10

params, cov = curve_fit( fit_func, T, I0, p0=[ Eg, c ] )
Eg, c = params
print( "Eg, c = ", Eg, c )

fit = c * T ** 3 * np.exp( -Eg / ( kB * T ) )

plt.plot( T, I0, 'o', label="data" )
plt.plot( T, fit, label="curve fit" )
plt.xlabel( "T" )
plt.ylabel( "I0" )
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I agree with lastchance's answer.

In order to check I compared with another method of fitting. This method (below) is a linear regression thus not iterative and not requiring "guessed" initial values. But the LMSE is wrt y=ln(Io) instead of wrt y=Io. Nethertheless the results are almost identical.

[image]

Conclusion : If the fitting deceives you this isn't due to the fitting calculus. This might be due either to large experimental deviation or to not very good model equation.